# Make all tabs of FragmentTabHost fit within screen

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a android app, with Tabs (`FragmentTabHost`).
I have a `FragmentActivity` with 6 tabs. At the moment the name of the tab is shown doing a line jump. I would like all tabs to fit in the width of the screen without having to do a horizontal scroll view. How can I show the tab names with good visualization. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the tabs enter without scrolling with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setMinimumWidth(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this change your xml layout like this

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Then in the onCreate after adding the tabs (also programmatically):

```
TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tw.getParent();
HorizontalScrollView hs = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
hs.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.addView(hs, 0);
ll.removeView(tw);
```

hs.addView(tw);
hs.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

Comment: I am not using tableyout, I am using fragments